# Is there an easy way to view matrix elements when debugging a C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix

I'm using complex matrices in my C# WPF application. I would like to view the matrix elements whilst debugging so as to ascertain correct operation of the application. I have tried entering the matrix name in the Watch list but all I get back is Value = DenseMatrix 3x3 Complex.

I have seen with Console applications that it is a trivial exercise to display the matrix entries in the console.

Looking for the best way to do it in WPF.

Thanks.

Comment: "it is a trivial exercise to display the matrix entries in the console" - you can use *exactly same code* and Visual studio will print result in Output window

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `ToString()` method and implement this to provide a nice way to visualize your matrix as a string. This will make it appear in the debugger when hovering over the object. You may need to format the values to have a fixed size to make all the columns align well.

If you cannot change the class you can still make an extension method, you will need to call this explicitly in an immediate panel or watch window, but this should at least make it possible to view.

It is also possible to create [custom data visualizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-visualizers-of-data?view=vs-2022), but I have never tried this, since visualizing values as strings has always been sufficient for my needs.

Comment: Do you perhpas have a codified example as I've never overridden the ToString method being a newbie to this. Thanks.

Comment: @Veritas The second google hit for "c# ToString": [How to override the ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

Answer (score 0):

Am struggling to get the ToString method to work. My code is summarised as follows:

```
public class LineFlex 
    {
        public double SideA       
        {
            get { return sideA; }
            set { sideA = value;}
        }


        internal void Calcs()
            {

            Complex D44 = new Complex(zD44real, zD44imag);
            Complex D45 = new Complex(zA12real, zD45imag);

            Complex D54 = new Complex(zA12real, zD54imag); 
            Complex D55 = new Complex(zD44real, zD44imag);

            Complex[,] arrayD = new Complex[2, 2] { { D44, D45 }, { D54, D55 } 
            };

            DenseMatrix MatrixD = DenseMatrix.OfArray(arrayD);

       }
    
public override string ToString()
        {
            return "MatrixD" + SideA;
        }
```

}

However, if I replace SideA with MatrixD (the one I want to view) in the override ToString() method:

```
public override string ToString()
            {
                return "MatrixD" + MatrixD;
            }
```

I get an error 'MatrixD does not exist in the current context'. MatrixD sits in the Calcs method in the same class so I thought the MatrixD is available to ToString() as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Solved, MatrixD is not global to the class as it's scope is limited to the Calcs method. Once I defined it globally error gone.